# Document directory structure after Updating version of the application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

What is  Document directory structure after Updating version of the application ?
is it replacing old with new Document Folder ? or it is just updating document folder ?

please help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing happens to your Document folder when you install a new version.  If you installed files that need to be updated for the new version, you will have to detect it and reinstall your new files from your bundle.

Comment: thanks for your  answer . here i am facing problem of "EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) " when i update version. why it happen any idea ?

Comment: Most likely because you've introduced a bug into your new code.  Does this happen when you run in the simulator?  Is there a message about the exception thrown in the Console window?  What's the stack trace look like?

Comment: its crashing on iPhone 3GS - iOS 4.0.1
and reason printed on console is - "Job appears to have crashed: Abort trap". I downloaded updated version app from app store .

Comment: This is your app, or an app you've purchased?  It may solve your problem to delete the app and reinstall it; of course, if it's your code, it would be better to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: I tried that I deleted old and then installed new then it works fine .
but problem with updating old with new .